# center div cutting into floated left div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-float

[image]I'm trying to align three divs horizontally.
The center div is cutting into the left div.
What am I doing wrong?

```
    <div>
      <div style={{width:"100px", border:"solid blue", float:"left"}}>Left some text some text some text</div>
      <div style={{width:"100px",  border:"solid green", float:"right"}}>Right</div>
      <div style={{border:"solid red", margin:"0 auto"}}>Center</div>
      <div style={{clear:"both"}}></div>
    </div>
```

The center overlaps the right green box as well but the border sizes are the same so you can't see it.

Comment: Did  the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Give the red div `margin-left:100px`:

```html
<div>
      <div style="width:100px;border:1px solid blue;float:left">Left some text some text some text</div>
      <div style="width:100px;border:1px solid green;float:right">Right</div>
      <div style="border:1px solid red;margin-left:100px">Center</div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You should use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) ? i think it's much more **convenient** and more **modern** than `"float"` conception. This my proposition.I hope You will be content ;-) If you want, you can switch from `width` to `flex` properties, they are commented in `css.`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.blue {
  width: 100px;
/*   flex: 1; */
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.green {
  width: 100px;
/*   flex: 1; */
  border:1px solid green;
}

.red {
  width: 100%;
/*   flex: 8; */
  border:1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="blue">Left some text some text some text</div>
  <div class="red">Center</div>
  <div class="green">Right</div>
</div>
```